# Create credit memo programatically - refund offline issue

Tags: magento-1, creditmemo

This is my code:

```
    $OldOrder = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId(3123121312);
    $invoices = $OldOrder->getInvoiceCollection();
    $service = Mage::getModel('sales/service_order', $OldOrder);
    foreach ($invoices as $invoice){
        $data = [];
        $data['shipping_amount'] = 0;
        $data['grand_total'] = 1;
        $data['base_grand_total'] = 1;
        $data['adjustment_positive'] = 1;
        $data['qtys'] = array(0 => 0);
        $creditmemo = $service->prepareInvoiceCreditmemo($invoice, $data);
        $creditmemo->setShippingAmount(0);
        $creditmemo->setGrandTotal(1);
        $creditmemo->setRefundRequested(true);
        $creditmemo->setOfflineRequested(false);
        $creditmemo->setPaymentRefundDisallowed(false);
        try {
            $creditmemo->refund();
        }catch(Exception $e){
            var_dump($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
```

I got no error, nothing, but the credit memo is not created . Any ideas why ?

Answer (score 0):

Chester you need to add one line

```
$creditMemo->load()
```

Before save or refund. Your code should be like this

```
$OldOrder = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId(3123121312);
    $invoices = $OldOrder->getInvoiceCollection();
    $service = Mage::getModel('sales/service_order', $OldOrder);
    foreach ($invoices as $invoice){
        $data = [];
        $data['shipping_amount'] = 0;
        $data['grand_total'] = 1;
        $data['base_grand_total'] =1;
        $data['adjustment_positive'] = 1;
        $data['qtys'] = array(0 => 0);
        $creditmemo = $service->prepareInvoiceCreditmemo($invoice, $data);
        $creditmemo->setShippingAmount(0);
        $creditmemo->setGrandTotal(1);
        $creditmemo->setRefundRequested(true);
        $creditmemo->setOfflineRequested(false);
        $creditmemo->setPaymentRefundDisallowed(false);
        $creditMemo->load();
        try {
            $creditmemo->refund();
        }catch(Exception $e){
            var_dump($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
```